# Is the father/brother/sister of a stepmother a grandfather/uncle/aunt?

Tags: kinship-terms

My daughter married a man with a twelve-year-old son. They had been dating for over five years. Now that they are married:

- Am I technically the boy’s grandfather?
- Are my daughter’s siblings his aunts or uncles?

Does getting married constitute those titles. What if they separate, do you now lose the titles because he is not a blood relative.

Comment: Is this about English Language ?

Comment: @Cascabel: Unless there this is about legal consequences of being related in some manner: No.

Comment: @Centaurus: Yes, it is. Different languages denote and comprise relations in a different manner.

Comment: It's not a bad question. Howevet, I think you'll find cultural differences. If you want to stay with Stack Exchange, the Christianity site might be a good place; although you'll have to specify a denomination. For a Jewish perspective, you might try "Ask the Rabbi" at chabad.org. Gentiles are welcome to ask.

Comment: What does religion have to do with this? Religion does not equal culture, it just interacts with it. It may be relevant if you want to interpret some doctrine that explicitly pertains to some kinship, but that depends on the original language of the doctrine (if you care about that) and does not necessarily have to have anything to do with everyday English language.

Comment: I would call you his step-grandfather, but I don't think there are any rules about what he has to call you.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, I think I would do the same. However describing someone as a step-grandfather does not clarify whether he is the boy's step-mother's father, or his mother's step-father; if that is important. Suppose he is the step-mother's step-father. Is he then a step-step grandfather?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft     The original question was **Does getting married to a person with an existing child get you athe title of aunt/uncle/grandfather**  That was when I made a comment.  And then you edited and changed the title.

Comment: @Centaurus: How does my edit change whether this is about the English language?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be his grandfather, and he wants to be your grandson, and you behave in a grandfatherly way towards him, and your daughter and his father have no objections, then you are grandfather and grandson.

The Queen's English supports this.  The son of the Queen, Prince Charles, called Lord Mountbatten his ["honorary grandfather"](http://royalcentral.co.uk/historic/lord-mountbatten-the-man-behind-prince-charles-55689). (Lord Mountbatten was his father's uncle.)

As for your daughter's siblings, they are the boy's aunts and uncles if they, the boy, your daughter and his father want them to be.

In English, the people involved choose the words in situations like this, and in the US, at least, it is nobody's business but their own what they choose.

(If your daughter and the boy's father divorce and you and the boy still have a close relationship, you can continue to be his grandfather if you and he want it.)

The legal ramifications (e.g., division of your estate if you die intestate) are beyond the scope of this site.